# How to obtain the level values of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working with a GUI for 3D images. I need to ajust the levels in one slice and then copy the levels to adjust all other slices.
In order to do something "user fiendly" I am using [`imcontrast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html), but the function does not return any value.

Is there any way to obtain the window levels of an image?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack [`imcontrast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html) build-in function (or better, clone it and create your own version `my_imcontrst.m`).
In the callback function `adjustButtonCallback` you have access to `clim` and `defaultRange` that are used as input arguments to `localAdjustData`. What you should do is use `clim` and `defaultRange` to adjust your entire volume.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear what you mean by 'obtain the window levels of an image' -  after using imcontrast on one slice you should be able to use [imhistmatch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhistmatch.html) on the remaining slices to match the histogram reference image / slice.

Alternatively, you could manually use [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) & [histeq](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) to respectively get & manipulate histogram data directly - that would require you add the necessary GUI.